# Как работает метод строк __add__ в python?

Tags: python, методы

Всем доброго времени суток. Недавно при определении пользовательского метода join строк столкнулся с интересной особенностью.

```
class MyStr(str):
    def join(self, obj):
        print('method join')
        
s = MyStr()
answer = s.join([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, [6, 7, [8, 9, [0]]]])
# output: method join
```

Здесь код работает как и ожидалось. Однако, если мы попробуем прибавить к строке другую строку, а затем вызвать метод join(), то будет вызвано исключение TypeError:

```
class MyStr(str):
    def join(self, obj):
        print('method join')
        
s = MyStr()
s += 'hello'
answer = s.join([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, [6, 7, [8, 9, [0]]]])
```

В чем разница?

Comment: Метод `__add__` возвращает `str` а не `MyStr`

Comment: Действительно. Однако, выглядит, как какая-то магия. Мы вызвали метод у объекта, после чего он перестал принадлежать классу MyStr()...

Comment: дело в том что `__add__` у `MyStr` наследуется у `str`, а `__add__` у `str` возвращает строку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

потому что `s` - это не строка, а ваш класс `MyStr`

когда без определения операции сложения (`__add__`) вы пытаетесь сложить его со строкой, то получаете на выходе строку

```
s = MyStr()
s += 'hello'
print(type(s)) # выведется <class 'str'>
```

а у строки метод `join()` работает с другими данными, а не теми, которые вы передаёте

Например можно сделать так, чтобы работало:

```
class MyStr(str):

    def join(self, obj):
        print('method join')

    def __add__(self, str):
        return MyStr(str)


s = MyStr()
s += 'hello'
answer = s.join([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, [6, 7, [8, 9, [0]]]])
```